# Eclipse Orion ignores .eslintrc

Tags: eclipse-orion

I'm using Eclipse Orion via local Orion server. Right now I'm trying to figure out how to get Orion to apply my custom .eslintrc file to the project instead of the linting rules provided by the IDE itself.
I have tried copying the .eslintrc into the project directory. According to the ESLint documentation, that's how you configure ESLint for a directory and all of its subdirectories. Unfortunately that did'nt affect linting in Orion. Also copying .eslintrc to the project's parent directory and several other locations didn't have any effect. So how can I get Orion to apply an .eslintrc file?

Comment: What version of Orion are you using? Our support for .eslintrc files was done for Orion 12.0.
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=461228

Comment: I have installed the latest release - 12.0. Found that bug report as well. Orion is still ignoring my .eslintrc. Do I have to provide a custom Orion plugin for my .eslintrc? I would love to use Orion! What is most important to me is to get JSX supported by the editor. Is there any easy way to achieve that without providing a custom .eslintrc?